# What do the letters "h" and "i" next to TCAS ND symbols mean?

Tags: airbus-a320, avionics, flight-simulator, tcas

What is the meaning of the letters **h** and **i** seen behind the relative altitude on the TCAS ND indication:

[image]

Comment: It is from the type-rating material. There isn’t any other information provided than the slide attached above.

Comment: It makes no sense. I've never seen n alpha character on that location on a TCAS display. As @757toga commented, the trend arrows are missing. On the map they should be to the right of the symbol. At the bottom, where the h and i are located. Perhaps in generating the presentation material someone got the wrong character set changing the arrows to the letters.

Comment: The aircraft type is A320.

Answer (score 18):

**They mean the simulator or mockup is buggy and Wingdings 3 was missing / broken / not selected.** There should be trend arrows there instead.

First smoking gun: this appears to be a photo of either a simulator or a mockup, as we can see from the Microsoft Windows mouse cursor:

[image]

Now, in many avionics software graphics engines - both for flight hardware and simulators (and of course for mockups) - it's common to use special fonts for symbology. In this case I'm guessing the "h" and "i" are meant to be rendered as trend arrows, using such a special font which has those symbols in place of normal letter glyphs.

Second smoking gun: check out Wingdings 3!

[image]

Character code 0x68 is "h" in normal fonts. 0x69 is "i" in normal fonts and a down arrow in Wingdings 3.

It should look more like this:

[image]

The trend arrows indicate that the target is climbing or descending.

Comment: Well done! Bounty on this answer as soon as the system will let me award it (24 hours, I think).

Comment: Thanks! I'm a software engineer (and pilot) and worked on professional flight simulators and avionics for 10 years so I had an advantage in spotting it.

Comment: Is there a way to crosspost this to StackOverflow? This is a fun confluence of computing and aviation bugs